# Pointer, Class and void* in C++

Tags: c++, class, void-pointers

I get a code for Fibonacci Heap. This code uses the follow function to compare two keys:

```
int
cmp(void *x, void *y)
{
    int a, b;
    a = (int)x;
    b = (int)y;

    if (a < b)
        return -1;
if (a == b)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

This works because the KEY is currently a INT number.

I would like to adapt this code to use my class called "Node". This class have implemented the operator <. >, <=, == and >=.

My adaptation in the code was:

```
Node a, b   // instead int a, b
a = (Node)x;
b = (Node)y;
```

But I get the error:

```
dijkstra.cpp:168: error: no matching function for call to 'Node::Node(void*&)'
graph.h:39: note: candidates are: Node::Node()
graph.h:39: note:                 Node::Node(const Node&)
```

I tried also:

```
Node a, b   // instead int a, b
a = (Node*)x;
b = (Node*)y;
```

and get the error:

```
dijkstra.cpp:168: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'a = (Node*)x'
graph.h:39: note: candidates are: Node& Node::operator=(const Node&)
```

I give up to try set the value and solve the question as a follow:

```
int cmp(void *x, void *y)
{ 
    if ((Node*)x < (Node*)y)
        return -1;
    if ((Node*)x == (Node*)x)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong in the previous examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `cmp` function casts the pointers to ints (obviously assuming they are of the same size), and then compares the pointers. Not the values pointed to. That makes no sense!

Comment: To downvoter: I did not understand why you did it, but pointer it is difficult concept and void-pointer mixed with class it worth.

Comment: @Bo Person: The initial code I do not have the INT value??

Comment: I am the downvoter and I told you why. :-) Using `void*` is just bad, as we cannot see what they are supposed to be. Casting to some other type just doesn't help. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Bo Person: I know void* is bad. But I get a piece of code for Fibonacci Heap and the way that code use to abstract the comparation is that. Now I have to delivery this, but in the future I will fix using Templates. But, thank you for your information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following lines

```
a = (Node*)x;
b = (Node*)y;
```

to

```
a = *( (Node*) x); 
// type cast from void* to Node* and then fetch the contents by dereferencing the pointer.

b = *( (Node*) y);
```

You were merely type casting the pointers from `void*` to `Node*` and trying to assign the pointer to a variable of type `Node`.

Comment: Since the OP is using C++, I think he can use static_cast, instead of the C style cast.

Comment: I think this asks my question. I will do some tests with this.

Comment: I'd use reference / pointers instead and avoid unnecessary copying of the object…

Answer (score 2):

You said you overloaded operators(<,==,etc..) for the Node class.  But the function compares pointers as is.  You need to dereference them in order to use your operators.  Try this:

```
int
cmp(void *x, void *y)
{
    Node *a, *b;
    a = (Node*)x;
    b = (Node*)y;

    if (*a < *b)
        return -1;
    if (*a == *b)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling the `cmp` function (or it is getting called via a callback) with a reference to the Node object. If that is the case you can change your code to

```
Node& a = static_cast<Node&>(*x);
Node& b = static_cast<Node&>(*y);
```

I am guessing this without looking at the calling code - which, honestly is not a good idea. If you can post the calling code too, it will be helpful to answer the question better.

Answer (score 1):

There no reason to compare (Node*) or (void*) values - this is just pointers and you will compare memory addresses. It looks like all you need to make first example work is implement `operator =`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what yasouser said, your first program will not work as expected.

```
a = *(int*)x;
b = *(int*)y;
```

Answer (score 1):

First about your cmp function itself:
 usually people only implement `operator<`; when `operator>` is implemented, it is usually through a call to the already implemented `operator<` with reversed parameters. Your implementation of cmp also requires the Node implement `operator==`, which might be unnecessary.

Also, there is a small issue if your function accepts void* but internally converts them to NODE* and dereferences them AND it yet it is named with a generic "cmp".

A better implementation would be this:

```
int NodeCmp(void *x, void *y)
{ 
// handle NULL pointers here
    if (*(Node*)x < *(Node*)y)
        return -1;
    if (*(Node*)y < *(Node*)x)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

If you're feeling up to it, you might want to look into std::less or template functions.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you are passing a `void*` to a function, you must then cast the pointer to another pointer of the type you are wanting.  For example:

```
void func(void* a, void* b)
{
    int* c, d;
    c = (int*)a;
    d = (int*)b;
    //... continue rest of function
}
```

You on the otherhand are trying to value initialize an object of type `T` when you write

```
(T)value;
```

or

```
T(value);
```

That is why you're getting complaints about not having a proper constructor type for the object of type `T`.

What you should be doing is casting to a pointer of type `T*`, and then *dereferencing* those new casted pointers to-do whatever comparisons you want between the *actual objects* of type `T`.  For example (assume `T` is some desired type you want to compare ... i.e., this is not a template):

```
int cmp(void* a, void* b)
{
    T* c, d;
    c = (T*)a;
    d = (T*)b;

    if (*c < *d)
        return -1;
    else if (*c > *d)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```